# Why is a ColdFusion SESSION variable "undefined" after being referenced a few lines before?

Tags: session, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Running ColdFusion 8.01 Standard on Windows2003/IIS6

Application.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
    <cfscript>
        THIS.SessionManagement = "Yes";
        THIS.SessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0, 3, 0, 0);
        THIS.ApplicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0, 8, 0, 0);
    </cfscript>

    <cffunction name="onRequestStart" returnType="Boolean" output="false">
        <cfargument name="targetPage" type="string" required="true">

        <cfscript>
            if  (!StructKeyExists(SESSION, "User"))
                SESSION.User = CreateObject("component", "cfc.User");
        </cfscript>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Template file Pseudo-Code Sample:

```
    LOCAL.qItems =
        CreateObject(
                "component",
                "cfc.Items"
                ).setUser(SESSION.User).getItems();

    for (i=1; i<=LOCAL.qItems.RECORDCOUNT; i++) {
        LOCAL.Item =
            CreateObject(
                "component",
                "cfc.Item"
                ).setUser(
                    SESSION.User
                    ).setId(LOCAL.qItems["Sku"][i]);
    }
```

SESSION.User is set (if not already defined) in `onRequestStart()` of `Application.cfc`. The above code runs in a template file. The second reference to `SESSION.User` has thrown an exception with the message `Element USER is undefined in SESSION`.

Why would SESSION.User be defined (doesn't throw an exception) a few lines before, and then throw this exception a few lines later (within milliseconds)?

This happens maybe once a day in different templates throughout my application.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, but you should really be init-ing your session variables in `onSessionStart()`, not `onRequestStart()`.

Comment: Maybe some users are working in your site with multiple tabs/windows, maybe one tab is doing something, but then they sign-out in another, thus destroying your session vars.  Or maybe after they sign-out in one tab they go back to a previous one and attempt some kind of action.  In my CF app if a user signs-out all other tabs are forced to sign out as well and return to the sign-in page.

Answer (score 7):

It's most likely a thread safety issue with something else in your code clearing out session scope or assigning NULL to `SESSION.User`.

I suggest that because you don't seem to have a local declaration for `i` in your loop, so that code is not thread safe - and so you may have similar errors elsewhere in your code.

Comment: so simply adding "i = 1;" before the for loop will make this piece of code thread safe?

Comment: No, you either need to do ' var i="" ' or ' local.i="" ' before the loop to make the "i" variable local to the function and thus thread safe.

Comment: Since you are on CF8 you have to use `var i = `.  The local scope was introduced in CF 9

Comment: It's not a function, it's a piece of cfscript in a CFM template - the default template in the root directory, as a matter of fact. So, not scoping a simple index will cause my SESSION to clear?

Comment: ALso, I would never reference or use SESSION variables in a function - bad practice....

Comment: How is that CFM template executed? Is it as part of a CFC? Just a plain CFM template invoked directly via a URL? Is it possible that multiple requests are running in the same session and one of those requests is deleting the user from session scope?

Answer (score 1):

I'd put this line "SESSION.User = CreateObject("component", "cfc.User");" into onSessionStart() then it will run when each users session is first initiated.

Comment: How will that solve my problem of a SESSION (or a property of the SESSION) disappearing in the middle of a template loading?