# ColdFusion 11: " Variable SESSION is undefined" Error

Tags: apache, session, coldfusion

## The Problem

I have just installed ColdFusion 11 Developer Edition on my computer to have my LocalHost environment match our recently-upgraded development and production environments.

But now, the same code that works everywhere else is failing on the new installation -- specifically:

- **The previous ColdFusion 9 LocalHost (which I am trying to replace with the new installation):** The code works.
- **ColdFusion 11 development and production environments:** The code works.
- **New ColdFusion 11 LocalHost:** The code fails with a "Variable SESSION is undefined" error.

## Attempted Solutions That Didn't Work

#### Trying What Was Done in Our Development & Production Servers

This error also occurred when our server administrator performed the upgrade from ColdFusion 9 to 11 in December, so I reached out to him to find out how he resolved it. A significant difference, though, is that he was installing on a Linux box, using an Apache web server, and I am installing on a Windows 7 computer using the ColdFusion 11 Developer Edition's built-in web server.

In any event, he told me that he had made two changes to resolve this error on his system:

1. In ColdFusion Administrator, make sure that all memory variables are enabled.
   **I did this, checking the following, and clicking Submit Changes:

   - Use J2EE session variables
   - Enable Application Variables *(was already checked)*
   - Enable Session Variables *(was already checked)***
2. In the Apache `global.conf` file, add the following lines:
   `RewriteEngine on`
   `RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{REMOTE_USER}]`
   `RewriteRule .* - [E=SCRIPT_NAME:%{REQUEST_URI}]`
   `RewriteRule .* - [E=AUTHENTICATE_CN:%{ENV:AUTHENTICATE_CN}]`
   `RewriteRule .* - [E=AUTHENTICATE_DEPARTMENTNUMBER:%{ENV:AUTHENTICATE_DEPARTMENTNUMBER}]`
   `RewriteRule .* - [E=AUTHENTICATE_GIVENNAME:%{ENV:AUTHENTICATE_GIVENNAME}]`
   `RewriteRule .* - [E=AUTHENTICATE_MAILALTERNATEADDRESS:%{ENV:AUTHENTICATE_MAILALTERNATEADDRESS}]`
   `RewriteRule .* - [E=AUTHENTICATE_MAIL:%{ENV:AUTHENTICATE_MAIL}]`
   `RewriteRule .* - [E=AUTHENTICATE_ORGANIZATIONALSTATUS:%{ENV:AUTHENTICATE_ORGANIZATIONALSTATUS}]`
   `RewriteRule .* - [E=AUTHENTICATE_SERIALNUMBER:%{ENV:AUTHENTICATE_SERIALNUMBER}]`
   `RewriteRule .* - [E=AUTHENTICATE_SN:%{ENV:AUTHENTICATE_SN}]`
   `RewriteRule .* - [E=AUTHENTICATE_TELEPHONENUMBER:%{ENV:AUTHENTICATE_TELEPHONENUMBER}]`
   `RewriteRule .* - [E=AUTHENTICATE_UID:%{ENV:AUTHENTICATE_UID}]`
   **I don't think this pertains to me though, as I'm using the built-in web server for this development installation, and don't see a `global.conf` file anywhere in my installation.**

#### Web Search: Adding Settings in `Application.cfc`

A web search was not very productive, but did lead me to a [very old instruction for ColdFusion 8](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=sharedVars_11.html). Based on that article, I tried adding the following lines to my `Application.cfc` file -- but this did not resolve the error:

```
<cfset this.sessionManagement = "Yes" >
<cfset this.name = "ApplicationName" >
```

#### Similar Answers on Stack Overflow

I searched for similar issues on Stack Overflow, but didn't find any promising leads. I [found one similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143449/why-is-a-coldfusion-session-variable-undefined-after-being-referenced-a-few-li), but that person seems to have a different problem than I'm experiencing: In his case, the `SESSION` variable exists (as he can demonstrate with `<cfdump>`, but is being ignored later in code. But in my case the `SESSION` variable doesn't seem to have been created in the first place.

I *did* try one of the suggestions there, however: adding the following to `onSessionStart()`:
`SESSION.User = CreateObject("component", "cfc.User");`

Unfortunately, this did not resolve the problem.

## Suspicion

I suspect that the crux of the issue is my use of the built-in server, and that I must add lines to a configuration file somewhere like our server administrator did with the Apache `global.conf` file.

Any ideas what I need to do to get my code working on this local ColdFusion 11 installation?

## Update: Resolution

Ultimately, the cause of the problem was a configuration issue (compounded by a flawed program design):

In the `OnApplicationStart()` function, there is a call to the database, which failed because I had neglected to install the appropriate `JAR` file on this new installation. This sent program execution to the `OnError()` function. In our case, the `OnError()` function includes some information from the `SESSION` variable in its report – but because program execution never finished the `OnApplicationStart()` function, it consequently never entered the `OnSessionStart()` function where the `SESSION` variable is created. And this led to the "Variable SESSION is undefined" error.

I have upvoted Kris's answer and marked it correct. (Well-done for a new user, Kris!)

Comment: A colleague just had a similar issue and the problem wound up being an error in code called from `onSessionStart`. This may cause an error like you are seeing, but in reality, it may be the symptom of another problem.

Comment: Very nice detective work!  Wish I could vote up this (and @Kris` answer) again for the troubleshooting approach and resolution alone :)  This kind of thread is like a "who-done-it" tale for programmers ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continue troubleshooting by determining if it's a problem with your install vs. your code. I would try creating a new site in Apache, using the CF server configuration tool, and then creating a new project in CFB. Create an Application.cfc file and index.cfm. In Application.cfc make sure you have `this.sessionManagement = true` and `this.clientManagement = true`. In index.cfm just `cfdump` the session. If this results in success you can look further into your existing code. If it fails you might want to try reinstalling CF.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you accidentally set the timeout params for session vars in CFAdmin to 0. It won't be unlimited, it will make the session scope go away.